# Getting missing-braces warning for pthread_mutex initialization in struct

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a `struct fifo` that contains types `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`.  Is there something special about these types that I shouldn't initialize them with `{0}`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct fifo {
        pthread_mutex_t head_mutex;
        pthread_cond_t cond_add;
};
typedef struct fifo fifo;

fifo* fifo_construct(fifo* self)
{
        *self = (fifo){
            {0}, /* head_mutex */
            {0}, /* cond_add */
        };

        pthread_mutex_init(&self->head_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&self->cond_add, NULL);

        return self;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        fifo f;
        fifo_construct(&f);

        pthread_mutex_t mut = {0}; // No complaint here!

        fprintf(stderr, "addr: %p, %p\n", &mut, &f.head_mutex);
}
```

Using `gcc -Wmissing-braces` (10.2.0) produces the following warning:

```
fifo.c: In function ‘fifo_construct’:
fifo.c:12:10: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
   12 |  *self = (fifo){
      |          ^
   13 |      {0}, /* head_mutex */
      |       {}
   14 |      {0}, /* cond_add */
      |       {}
```

But it doesn't complain about the initialization in main.  Am I missing something or is the compiler just being picky?

Comment: These are supposedly opaque so we shouldn't know or care what's inside those types. Correct use is to call `pthread_cond_init` and so on. Why do you think you need to zero-initialize them?

Comment: @Lundin I suppose I don't have to.   There are other methods.  This is just how I chose to initialize `struct fifo` which, in the actual code, has over 10 members.  I just condensed it to re-produce the warning.  I actually initialize every struct in my project in this manner, yet this is the only one it complains about.

Comment: gcc is pretty shaky overall when it comes to warnings for nested "aggregates" and designated initializers. I'd just initialize the members that actually _need_ to be initialized, the rest will get zeroed anyway.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but it looks like you can specify the field names and use the static? initializers without any errors or warnings: `.head_mutex = THREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, .cond_add = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,` https://godbolt.org/z/P3Tvn8WYn , then, no need for the init function calls.

Comment: If `struct fifo` contains only the members shown, and you're initializing the mutex and CV with the appropriate functions anyway, as shown, then you don't need that compound literal at all.  Just omit the whole `*self = ...` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a `struct fifo` that contains types `pthread_mutex_t` and
> `pthread_cond_t`. Is there something special about these types that I
> shouldn't initialize them with `{0}`?

Not as far as the C language is concerned. `{0}` is a valid initializer for an object of any type.  That does not imply, however, that the resulting mutex or CV value is a valid one as far at the pthreads level.

> Using gcc -Wmissing-braces (10.2.0) produces the following warning: [...]

This is a style warning, which you could obtain from similar initializers for any number of similar structure types.  It does not necessarily imply that there is anything is wrong with your code. GCC just thinks that it's a risky approach, notwithstanding that the special case of the `{0}` initializer form is utterly idiomatic.

Other options include

- Using the initializer macros that pthreads provides for these types<sup>*</sup>:

  ```
  *self = (fifo) { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER };
  ```

  In this case, you do not need to also call the initialization functions unless you want non-default properties.
- Omit any explicit initializers for those members.
- If, as in the example code, the mutex and CV are the only members, or if you do not care to initialize any others, then drop the whole assignment statement with its compound literal.  You don't need to pre-initialize the mutex and CV when you are anyway going to initialize them via their initialization functions before using them.
- Turn off the warning with `-Wno-missing-braces`

---

<sup>*</sup>Older versions of the POSIX specifications only promise that these can be used for objects having static storage duration, but that caveat has been dropped from recent versions.

Comment: "Not as far as the C language is concerned. {0} is a valid initializer for an object of any type."  This is what I was concerned about.  Thank you for your help!